# Заполнить datagridview второй формы из первой

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 формы. На форме 1 таблица и кнопка, по нажатию которой должен заполняться второй datagridview. Когда оба грида на одной форме, то все работает нормально. А как сделать, чтобы на 1 форме был один грид и кнопка и по нажатию кнопки открывалась вторая форма с гридом и он заполнялся на второй форме?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Square();
}

public void Square()
{
    int n = t1DataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;
    string[] labels = new string[n];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = Convert.ToString(t1DataGridView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        dt.Columns.Add(labels[i]);
        dt.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = labels[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Сходу могу предложить два способа. Первый - запомнить все данные, которые необходимо скопировать, и передать их в конструктор второй формы. Второй - сделать грид на второй форме публичным и обращаться к нему напрямую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно создать 2ю форму. `Ctrl+Shift+A -> Windows Forms -> Форма Windows Forms`. Затем нужно добавить контрол dataGridView на 2ю форму. Можно добавить в конструкторе формы, можно программным путем. Сразу же сделаем контрол `dataGridView` открытым, что бы можно было обращаться к нему из класса 1ой формы. Для этого в свойствах контрола сделаем параметр `Modifiers -> Public`. Затем настроим обработку нужной нам кнопочки.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            // создаем объект 2ой формы
            Form2 f = new Form2();

            //теперь обращаться к контролу dataGridView
            //можно через объект формы таким образом
            //к примеру, зададим размерность dataGridView
            f.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
            f.dataGridView1.RowCount = n;

            //открываем форму
            f.ShowDialog();
    }
```